# Mockito: null object in class to test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to junit and mockito, so the problem might be an obvious one.
I have an issue with mockito where a locally instantiated object within the 'test object' is null. There are no private / protected / final methods being called in this particular section, so that is not the issue. 
Also I am using PowerMockito for other private method calls.

section of my class to test:
null pointer exception being thrown on user.getId() - last line here:

```
SupportProdUpdatesImpl pAdd = new SupportProdUpdatesImpl();       
Add.setQueryProcssStatus(form.getQueryProcssStatus());          

pAdd.setQueryTitle(form.getQueryTitle().toUpperCase());         
pAdd.setQueryType(form.getQueryType().toUpperCase());

logger.debug("*** query String = " + form.getQuerySQL() );
    pAdd.setQuerySQL(StringUtils.trim(form.getQuerySQL()));
    pAdd.setMakerId(user.getId());
```

In my test i have created a

```
User user = mock(User.class) // interface of user
when(user.getId()).thenReturn(new Integer(111)));
```

I do not understand what i am doing wrong.. Any help would be appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Which runner have you defined? @RunWith

Comment: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({WebApplicationContextUtils.class}) I need that runner in order to overcome a protected method so i can inject mock context

Comment: Is mock(User.class) invoking a Mockito method? Usually you would go for PowerMock.createMock(User.class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is going on is that you have not provided the `user` mock to the class under test.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given spy a try instead of mock?
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13